# Site icons are misplaced

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, top-bar, favicon

### Description

I noticed it for the Programmers site icon, but looks like it also happens with other site's (like Super User) icons too. See the pics below (excuse me for the lack of freehand circles):

### Use-Case

I'm under OS X 10.9.5 with Chrome version 45.0.2454.101 (64-bit).

### Attachments

#### On the MultiColider

[image: Icon problem on the MultiColider]

#### On the achievements panel

[image: Icon problem on the achievements panel]

### Solution

The problem is with this CSS rule (and with his friends):

```
.favicon-programmers {
    background-position: 0 -4086px;
}
```

Comment: Great that someone else had already posted this =) Was confused why there are some "unfamiliar logos" in the list of hot questions.

Comment: I don't have problem in 'multi-colider' and 'achievements panel' BUT I do see sites icons misplaced in the 'Hot Network Questions'

Comment: Also on Chrome and Chromium/web kit on Android 4.4. Happens with many icons, not just Programmers.

Comment: They also appear to be misplaced in the profile pages if you scroll down to see the top five network profiles.

Comment: We rebuilt the sprite maps earlier today after launching a new design for Skeptics, so perhaps something went wrong there. Will ping a designer and take a closer look in the morning.

Comment: I actually can't reproduce this here (Windows 10, Chrome). To the Macbook!

Comment: Its happening on windows 10 -  chrome canary (48.0.2530.0)and firefox 41.0.1 for me.  Maybe you have the old images cached? If it matters I have one highdpi display but its happening on both my 1080p (at 100% ui scaling) and my 2180p (125% ui scaling) displays.

Comment: It happens on the [mobile UI too](http://i.imgur.com/7UjEVHr.png).

Comment: Also happening on the HNQ list

Comment: Yeah, it's far more likely that something's actually broken... even though "works on my machine" is pretty comforting. :) I'll dig into this in the morning.

Comment: @AnnaLear I only see this on a Retina screen. If I drag the browser to a non-retina screen, the icons are OK again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Good catch. We pushed a fix. Everything should be back to normal now.

Comment: Confirmed in my end, Android chrome/chromium