# Why are my HNQ site icons offset?

Tags: support, design, hot-questions, sidebar

All (well, most of) the icons for sites in my Hot Network Questions sidebar are misaligned or otherwise broken:

[image]

I'm seeing this on all of my devices (MacBook, iMac, iPhone), which are all using Safari. It curiously does *not* appear to happen on meta SE, but it does happen on every other site I've tried. It's been happening since at least last night.

I realize this issue has been reported before

- [HNQ site icons are borked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270004/hnq-site-icons-are-borked)
- [Site icons are misplaced](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267620/site-icons-are-misplaced)
- [Site icons misaligned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270001/site-icons-misaligned)

but all of those issues are old (from fall 2015) and reported as fixed. Has the issue re-appeared, or am I doing something dumb on my end?

Comment: Can you check with Chrome/Firefox to see if it's Safari only bug?

Comment: This happens on all sites? Different sites? Also when browsing on HTTPS? Did you try a hard refresh/clearing the caches?

Comment: This can happen either because the generated sprite sheet had a bad icon (say one 32*32 in a sheet that is all 16*16) or if the generated CSS for it is off. The issues we've had with generated files have been fixed in the past, and given that this has only been reported by yourself (with a single upvote), I suspect it is very localized. Meaning - possibly you ISP is caching a bad old file (or another cache between yourself and our CDN).

Comment: I'm seeing this with Chrome, Firefox and Safari, after clearing caches, over HTTP and HTTPS. I wrote a bug report mistakenly at meta.SO here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327377/hnq-site-icons-misaligned. It isn't happening on all sites. I suspect it might be an ISP cache (I'm on Comcast in the USA).

Comment: Yup, my situation is the same as @nneonneo, although I didn't test Firefox. Also on Comcast, so maybe that's the problem.

Comment: @JoshPetrie: Are you perchance in Seattle? I just checked the offending spritesheet https://cdn.sstatic.net/img/favicons-sprite32.png?v=deee83c5ac83. It should be 32x12276 pixels, which is what I get via `wget`. But, in my browser, it always comes up 32x12240 pixels. The headers indicate that a Varnish cache server in Seattle (`cache-sea1924-SEA`) is responsible for this.

Comment: Cute, it might be a Varnish bug. If I use `curl -vvvvv 'https://cdn.sstatic.net/img/favicons-sprite32.png?v=deee83c5ac83' --compressed -O`, I get the wrong (old) 32x12240 image; if I use `curl -vvvvv 'https://cdn.sstatic.net/img/favicons-sprite32.png?v=deee83c5ac83' -O` I get the right image.

Comment: @nneonneo Yes, I'm in Seattle. :D

Comment: @Oded isn't this a no-repro bug? (i.e. the behavior itself as seen in the screenshot looks like a bug, but it can't be reproduced)

Comment: @ShadowWizard - as seen by the comments, if anything, it is a bug in the proxy that comcast is using near Seattle... not really something we control or can control.

Comment: Yet another reason to use HTTPS..

Answer (score 2):

This appears to have been resolved, I think @nneonneo's theory that it was a caching problem was correct.

Comment: Glad things are working now. Seemed very localized and not under the control of SE.