# Site icons misplaced

Tags: bug, status-completed

Site icons are misaligned in many places across Stack Exchange.

Seems like a duplicate of those old bugs which had been fixed:

- [Site icons misaligned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270001/site-icons-misaligned)
- [Site icons are misplaced](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267620/site-icons-are-misplaced)

Here's what I see now on Windows 10 Chrome 52.0.2743.82 beta-m (64-bit):

[image]

on Android (Chrome 51.0.2704.81):

[image]

I've cleared the cache and tried incognito mode, as well as Firefox 47.0.1, problem persists.

**Update:**

Icons are ok on http://meta.stackexchange.com but are misplaced on http://stackoverflow.com and http://russian.stackexchange.com

**Update 2:**

Here's what I get with requests from two different IP addresses:

Request from an IP in Great Britain (correct response):

```
alex@dev1:~$ curl 'https://cdn.sstatic.net/img/favicons-sprite32.png?v=df4c1382a05c' -H 'Host: cdn.sstatic.net' -H 'Pragma: no-cache' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br' -H 'Accept-Language: ru,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6' -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' -H 'X-Compress: null' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.82 Safari/537.36' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' --compressed -o /dev/null -s -D - --resolve cdn.sstatic.net:443:151.101.129.69
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: max-age=604800
Content-Type: image/png
Last-Modified: Tue, 19 Jul 2016 17:22:46 GMT
ETag: "6366782ae2e1d11:0"
Content-Length: 203313
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Thu, 21 Jul 2016 16:57:07 GMT
Via: 1.1 varnish
Age: 171124
Connection: keep-alive
X-Served-By: cache-lcy1132-LCY
X-Cache: HIT
X-Cache-Hits: 12641
X-Timer: S1469120227.487221,VS0,VE0
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

Request from an IP in Russia (incorrect response, see the `Content-Length`):

```
[abolen@wind ~]$ curl 'https://cdn.sstatic.net/img/favicons-sprite32.png?v=df4c1382a05c' -H 'Host: cdn.sstatic.net' -H 'Pragma: no-cache' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br' -H 'Accept-Language: ru,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6' -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' -H 'X-Compress: null' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.82 Safari/537.36' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' --compressed -o /dev/null -s -D - --resolve cdn.sstatic.net:443:151.101.129.69
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: max-age=604800
Content-Type: image/png
Last-Modified: Tue, 19 Jul 2016 16:45:32 GMT
ETag: "9864faf6dce1d11:0"
Content-Length: 202798
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Thu, 21 Jul 2016 16:59:10 GMT
Via: 1.1 varnish
Age: 171288
Connection: keep-alive
X-Served-By: cache-bma7021-BMA
X-Cache: HIT
X-Cache-Hits: 15
X-Timer: S1469120350.547303,VS0,VE0
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

I've tried to rule out as many variables as possible, however the different IP addresses apparently get served by different Varnish endpoints.

Comment: Try clearing your cache and doing a hard refresh - you are probably loading an old version of the CSS.

Comment: @Oded: trust me, I wouldn't have posted it in the first place before doing this.

Comment: Well... not everybody does before posting ;) - it could be a proxy between you and us serving up an old version.

Comment: @Oded: there is no proxy. Just tried the backup provider and the mobile provider (both in porn mode), the same thing.

Comment: Could very well be something your ISP is doing or a caching proxy between you and us.

Comment: @Oded: interestingly enough, the sites look fine from a browserstack account. Do you maybe have different caching servers for different areas?

Comment: We do use a CDN for static content, but we also cache break newer versions.

Comment: @Oded: apparently you don't always, because browserstack and my home computers receive different versions of https://cdn.sstatic.net/img/favicons-sprite32.png?v=df4c1382a05c (note the HTTPS). `X-Served-By:cache-bma7024-BMA` (home), `X-Served-By:cache-ams4144-AMS` (browserstack). Content lengths differ.

Comment: But see that `?v=`? It should cause a cache break. If you change the value you should see the same file. I don't know what `BMA` is, but I don't think it is us.

Comment: @Oded: out of curiosity, are you shibboleet compatible? https://xkcd.com/806/

Comment: Only in the sense that it is a Hebrew word and as an Israeli I am a native speaker of Hebrew ;)

Comment: @Oded: OK. Different `X-Served-By` headers mean that the file is served by different Varnish servers, most probably selected based on GeoIP. The server which serves Mother Russia and vicinity serves a wrong, outdated version of the file. It's `202798` bytes long, not `203313` as it should be. This server identifies itself as `cache-bma7023-BMA`. Could you please locate someone who is responsible for Varnish caching and ask them to issue a `PURGE` request against this resource on this server? Thanks!

Comment: Purge issued. How does it look now?

Comment: @Oded: unfortunately, the same. If I remove or change the `v` parameter, it serves the right file (12348 pixels high, 203313 bytes long).

Comment: @Oded: see the curl script in my update to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Quassnoi any user scripts? Have you tried with a clean browser?

Comment: @ShadowWizard: *sigh* user scripts in curl?

Comment: No idea, it just sounds like something on your end and I trust testing with actual browsers.

Comment: @shadowwizard: testing with actual browsers is why I posted this in the first place. Yes, I tried with three different clean browsers, as you can read in the post. As I said in my update, the problem is same request for the same url gets served different content __over https__. That's hardly something on my end.

Comment: I read the post, clearing cache and going Incognito doesn't disable user scripts and plugins, though thinking about it hard to believe you have "cross browser" scripts. Anyway, if it was on SE end, we would see many users reproducing this, and that's not the case. Maybe your ISP is misbehaving by caching that response? I really can't see any other reason by now.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: how can my ISP cache HTTPS responses? You don't see many users reproducing this because only a part or your Varnish caching servers is affected (those with `X-Served-By` ending in `BMA`). As I said in my post, it's OK for users from Great Britain, who apparently get served by another server cluster. It's Russian IP ranges that are affected.

Comment: I am still looking at this - looks like the CDN Varnish node isn't working correctly. One of the SREs here will take a look and escalate as needed.

Comment: I issued another purge request, which seems to have taken now. Our Russian community manager reports that the icons now look fine.

Comment: @Oded any chance for another purge please? It [happened again](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283801/icons-for-some-sites-look-like-messed-up-in-user-profile).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just been talking to Fastly regarding this caching issue, and they have reported that all of our caches are up to date, and we are seeing the correct data now returned from RU.

Looks like the 2nd purge that Oded issued may have resolved the problem.

Comment: It works now, thanks a lot!