# Incorrect icon assigned when navigating from chat

Tags: bug

When navigating from chat, the Writers Stack Exchange seems to be assigned the World Building Stack Exchange icon. I am using Firefox 57.0 on Ubuntu.

[image: Wrong icon]

The error was duplicatable upon revisit.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303883/274942.