# Viewing reputation notifications on chat.SE shows the wrong favicons

Tags: bug, chat, notifications, achievements-dialog, favicon

I just got some rep notifications while I was chatting on chat.SE. Thanks to [this awesome script](https://stackapps.com/q/7404/43962), I have a top bar in chat, so I see something like this:

[image]

Now, suspecting that something may be wrong with the script showing it in the chat rooms, I went to the main chat.SE site, and... saw this same error.

[image]

To be sure, I spun up an incognito tab, where I don't have any scripts running (because normally I have 20+). And... still shows broken:

[image]

Apparently, English Language & Usage is now Stack Overflow en Español, Literature is now Magento, Mythology & Folklore is Network Engineering... Science Fiction & Fantasy and Meta don't seem to have been affected.

Comment: I can confirm this. Apparently magento is not martial arts (not that I mind :D) : https://i.imgur.com/dMg0KhZ.png Stackoverflow does not seem to be affected.

Comment: We renamed Mythology and CogSci recently, so the favicon spritemap changed. The cache should update itself eventually and fix the problem.

Comment: Looks like the same bug as [last time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303883/icons-for-hot-questions-are-wrong) when the site list changed. @JonEricson, could you please ask somebody at SE to find out why the CSS and/or the sprite sheet updates aren't getting properly pushed out and fix them? The client-side cache breakers in the URLs are (AFAICT) working as designed, so it looks like an issue with SE's deployment process and/or with the CDN. (The fact that it only seems to affect some users each time also kind of suggests a CDN issue to me.)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: It is a CDN issue. There's a race condition with the cache breakers and purging does not seem to work reliably. It's difficult for us to diagnose since we can never reproduce the problem ourselves.